# Precedence of div wrapping, will wrap inner or outer div?

Tags: css

Hard to explain, just look at example:
http://jsfiddle.net/tskoda/0qo8e2f6/4/

If you narrow output window, all 3 red boxes get put into new line.
Instead I want only 1 red box to be put into new line, right of green box.

The reason i need this is because i wanna create true fluid website, with 100% width, and i dont wanna use bootstrap, web programming is best done with basic components.

Code:

```
<div class="sidebar">
    <div>line 1</div>
    <div>line 2</div>
    <div>line 3</div>
</div>
<div class="content">
    <div>item</div>
    <div>item</div>
    <div>item</div>
</div>
```

```css
.sidebar {
    background:green;
    display:inline-block;
    /*max-width:100px;*/
}
.content {
    display:inline-block;
}
.content >div {
    display:inline-block;
    background: red;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
}
div{
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Set your `.content` container to have an `inline` display instead of `inline-block`.

```css
.content {
    display:inline;
}
```

[**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/0qo8e2f6/5/).

Comment: How do I prevent red box to be aligned to extreme left when it wraps? It should be aligned right of green box.

Comment: @ToneŠkoda I don't know what you mean, sorry.